# Pivoting a Dataframe Into An Array With Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Suppose we have the following example:

```
import pandas as pd


data = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv'

df=pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=';')
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

Ypre = df.pivot_table(values= 'packspercapita', index='year', columns=['state']).to_numpy()

Ypre
```

What I've done, is reshaped a dataframe to wide and converted it into a matrix, where state packs per capita are our columns and the row of the matrix is time (years in this case). I want to do this, but *only* for years before 1989. I could just as easily do

```
import pandas as pd


data = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/synth-inference/synthdid/master/data/california_prop99.csv'

df=pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=';')
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower()

dfpre = df[(df['year'] <= 1988)]

Ypre = dfpre.pivot_table(values= 'packspercapita', index='year', columns=['state']).to_numpy()

Ypre
```

but I don't want to if I do not need to. Is this possible?

Comment: *I could just as easily do ... but I don't want to if I do not need to* - doubts run on?

Comment: I don't understand. @RomanPerekhrest "Doubts run on"? All I'm asking for is if it's possible to do what my second block of code does, without needing to make the dfpre dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=';').rename(columns=str.lower)
​
Ypre = (df.pivot_table(values= 'packspercapita',
                          index='year', columns=['state']).loc[:1988].to_numpy())
```

Output :

```
print(Ypre)

array([[ 89.80000305, 100.3000031 , 123.        , 124.8000031 ,
        120.        , 155.        , 109.9000015 , 102.4000015 ,
        124.8000031 , 134.6000061 , 108.5       , 114.        ,
        155.8000031 , 115.9000015 , 128.5       , 104.3000031 ,
         93.40000153, 121.3000031 , 111.1999969 , 108.0999985 ,
        189.5       , 265.7000122 ,  90.        , 172.3999939 ,
        ...           ...           ...           ...
```

Comment: This seems like part of the solution, but when I run my code from top to bottom with your `Ypre` as you've defined it, `print(Ypre)` produces no output, and no array is saved when I try to save it as a CSV file. @Timeless EDIT: nevermind, it worked when I typed it out myself instead of copying and pasting it.

Comment: Are you sure ? I re-run the code again and I got the same output that I show in my answer. Can you *double-check* ?